# Kafka KStream to KStream left join not matching as expected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I have a Kafka Streams topology that starts with a KStream from a topic of *Event* messages. Each *Event* has a *Patient ID*. This KStream then joins with a patient demographics KStream to enhance the resulting value's patient information.

Both topics have 30 partitions and both use the *Patient ID* as the key. Therefore it's co-partitioned and the data in both topics are sharded based on the same key.

The problem is that even though every patient is in TOPIC_PATIENT_INFO, quite often the demographic record isn't found in the left join. For example, in the ValueJoiner below, the *demog* object will be null.

```
KStream<Integer, GenericRecord> ksEvents = builder.stream(TOPIC_EVENTS);
KStream<Integer, GenericRecord> ksDemogs = builder.stream(TOPIC_PATIENT_INFO);

ksEvents
 .peek((key, value) -> log.info("before join k:{}, v:{}", key, value))
 .leftJoin(ksDemogs, getValueJoinerWithKey(), JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(500000)))     
 .peek((key, value) -> log.info("after join k:{}, v:{}", key, value))
```

elsewhere in the code:

```
ValueJoinerWithKey<Integer, GenericRecord, GenericRecord, GenericRecord> getValueJoinerWithKey() {
    return (key, event, demog) -> {
       // demog *should* never be null because every patient ID is in the patient_info topic.
    }
}
```

For the demographics, I could have used a *GlobalKTable* instead of a *KStream* yet this would remove the advantage of co-partitioning and require that all instances of the streaming app contain all the demographic records; I'd like to use sharding if possible.

FYI: the large JoinWindow is to guarantee that no demographic records are ignored based on having an older timestamp.

Comment: _guarantee that no demographic records are ignored based on having an older timestamp_ - Then why not create a table for those events, and join the stream to the int ID in the table, and ignore timestamps?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: create a table for the demographics? I did convert the stream to a table but had the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes, but you'll probably want to use remote statestore lookups to do joins against many partitions.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I'd prefer to join a the primary KStream with a KTable indexed with the same key to enhance the Value with lookup data. This way I take advantage of sharding (with I don't get with GKTable or storage). Is this possible nor not?